# How to remove other apps icons (like Skype or WhatsApp) from contact and phone app?

Tags: contacts, calls, skype

I would like to keep Skype Mobile installed but get rid of its icons from contacts **AND/OR** from being asked whether I want to make a call to the contact through Skype or other similarly annoying application. Is there any facility in Android that allows me to keep the control of that? Uncle Google isn't much helpful in that matter.

Moreover I have two Skype icons per contact on my phone. And that the thing that hits my taste.

Phone details: Sony Xperia S, Android 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

go to Settings > Accouts and choose Skype/WhatsApp > then search for each one how do you remove the sync contacts. After this your Contacts list should update not showing Skype/WhatsApp data.

As for the call using skype, you should have the option to choose Phone and click Use Always.

This is very phone dependent, so if you cannot find this options, tell us more about your phone and Android version.

Comment: I selected once "Use Always" for calls, now the simpler dialog appears with two buttons, Skype and Phone Call. It just requires to tap one of options, no additional buttons at the bottom.

I've added phone details to the question content.

Comment: Additional subquestion: Selecting remove account informs me that this will delete all related account information from the phone, is it means that it will remove my account from the Skype application itself?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Contacts app and hit the menu key - choose 'Contacts to display' - you can choose to display contacts from a single app source or click on Customized list and it's setting button to choose which app sources to show contact data from and which ones to ignore.